# Effect of option --usermap, but for older rsync

Tags: linux, ssh, nas, rsync

I would like to run a `rsync` command to copy data from my laptop (Linux Mint) to my NAS (Synology) over SSH. I would like to also use the `--usermap` option. However, the version of `rsync` on the NAS is older (3.0.9) and does not support this option. Updating `rsync` on the NAS is difficult and I would like to avoid it. So my question:

Is there any way that I can simulate the effect of the `--usermap` option with a single `rsync` command using version 3.0.9 in the remote machine?